# I upload an image to firebase storage but i can't see image in firebase storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

First this is about my uploadImage code, I try to fix it again and again but doesn't work

```
Future uploadImageFile() async
  {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("Chat Images").child(fileName);

    StorageUploadTask storageUploadTask = storageReference.putFile(imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await storageUploadTask.onComplete;

    storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadUrl){
      
      imageUrl = downloadUrl;
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        onSendMessage(imageUrl, 1);
      });
    }, onError: (error){
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error: " + error);
    });
  }
```

And after in click upload image the result in terminal like this :

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'PlatformException' is not a subtype of type 'String'
#0      ChatScreenState.uploadImageFile.<anonymous closure> (package:telegramchatapp/Pages/ChattingPage.dart:726:47)
#1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
#2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:178:22)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:779:47)
#5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:800:13)
#6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:610:5)
#7      _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:276:13)
#8      StorageReference.getDownloadURL (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you show in your question comes from this line:

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error: " + error);
```

The `error` in here is not a string, so you can't concatenate it to a string. What you want is:

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error: " + error.toString());
```

Or:

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Error: $error");
```

That will then show you what the root cause of the upload failure is, so you can address that.

Comment: Thank for first question sir, After i fix follow you have a problem can i ask you?

Comment: Sure. But if it's non-trivial it'll be hard to help here, and I might ask you to open a new question for it.

Comment: Thank a lot sir, now i can fix it already i change command in firebase rule in if conditional it's work! thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple function to upload to Firebase Storage that works for me:

storage.dart

```
  Future upload({required String ref, required File file}) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).putFile(file).catchError(
          (e) => Utils.log(
            e,
            type: LogType.error,
          ),
        );
  }

  Future<String> downloadURL({required String ref}) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(ref).getDownloadURL().catchError(
          (e) => Utils.log(
            e,
            type: LogType.error,
          ),
        );
  }
```

This `Utils.log()` is just a logger, you can use Toast if you want. And this is how I use it:

anywhere_else.dart:

```
  String ref = 'users/${Services.auth.currentUser()!.uid}/selfie.png';

  var upload = await Services.storage.upload(ref: ref, file: selfie);

  if (upload != null) {
    user.selfie = await Services.storage.downloadURL(ref: ref);
  }
```